# MediatorLiveData onChanged is not firing with ROOM + Viewmodel

Tags: java, android

I tried to implement MediatorLiveData to listen for the changes in my LiveData due to Query Calls.

I tried to attach an observer to it but the method onchanged is never firing

My MainActivity:

```
final MediatorLiveData<List<Reminder>> liveDataMerger = new 
final LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

liveDataMerger.observe(new LifecycleOwner() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
                return lifecycleRegistry;
            }
        }, new Observer<List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Reminder> reminders) {
                if(reminders != null) {
                    reminderAdapter.setAdapterlist(reminders);
                    reminderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });



        viewModel.getLiveReminderList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Reminder> reminders) {
                if(reminders != null) {
                    reminderAdapter.setAdapterlist(reminders);
                    reminderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });


        liveDataMerger.addSource(viewModel.getLiveReminderList(),new Observer<List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Reminder> reminders) {
                int i = 121;
                if(reminders != null) {
                    liveDataMerger.setValue(reminders);
                    reminderAdapter.setAdapterlist(reminders);
                    reminderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

I want the onchanged method to fire.

Comment: Who is observing the `liveDataMerger`? Someone has to observe that to have the `MediatorLiveData` start observing its sources.

Comment: updated my answer!